# Linear independence, invertibility and the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, determinant

I'm trying the following proof:

Suppose that $A$ is an $nxn$ matrix. Show that if $A$ has linearly dependent rows, then $\det(A) = 0$.

My attempt:

I considered two approaches, namely, a direct proof vs proof by contrapositive. Off the bat, I realized that proof by contrapositive (i.e. $\det(A) \neq 0 \implies$ invertibility $\implies$ linearly independent columns) didn't seem to work. I decided to use a direct proof, as follows:

Suppose $A_1, ..., A_n$ are linearly dependent rows of $A$. By definition, there are scalars $c_1, ..., c_n$ s.t. $c_1A_1 + ... + c_nA_n = 0$, where not all $c_i$ are $0$ for $i = 1, ..., n$. Let $c_j$ be the non-zero coefficient with corresponding row $A_j$ where $j \in {1, ..., n}$, then:

$$A_j = -\frac{c_1}{c_j}A_1 - ... - \frac{c_n}{c_j}A_n$$

Let $B$ be the matrix obtained after performing the series of operations above on row $A_j$, then $A_j = (0\space ... \space 0)$. Also, by $n$-linearity, $\det(B) = \det(A)$. Moreover:

$$\det(B) = \sum_{\sigma} (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) A_{1\sigma_1} \cdots A_{n\sigma_n}$$

Notice that each product in the summand above contains an entry from row $A_j$. Hence, $\det(B) = \det(A) = 0$

QED.

I was curious if my proof above is correct. It was a little confusing at points and I'm not sure if showing the last 'observation' as a proof is necessary. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Also, out of sheer curiosity, would proof by contrapositive work?

Edit: Sorry for a few typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, your proof looks good. There are some indexing issues in your $A_j=-c_1/c_jA_1+\cdots$ line, but I assume these are all typos, and you probably want to say something like "fix some $1\leq j\leq n$ for which $c_j\neq 0$" instead of "let $c_j$ be the non-zero coefficient," as there could be multiple nonzero $c_j$. Otherwise, everything looks good.

Whether the last observation (that a matrix with an entirely $0$ row has determinant $0$) is necessary depends on the amount of rigor you're looking for (e.g. if this is for a class where proof-writing is a focus, etc.), and I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all answer. There's certainly no harm in including it, especially if the goal is for your solution to be as clear as possible, but it might end up being cumbersome if this proof is part of some longer document or solution. In most scenarios, I'd imagine it would be fine to just state that a matrix with an entirely $0$ row has $0$ determinant, and maybe cite "expansion by minors" or "the permutation sum formula" or something like that.

Re: proof by contradiction: this sort of depends on what you're assuming. There are so many different definitions of the determinant, and it takes a good bit of work to determine that they're all equivalent. For the definition based on volumes of parallelepipeds, for example, the implication $\det(A)\neq 0\implies \text{invertibility}$ is not difficult, but it's not obvious given the "sum of permutations" definition you've cited in your proof. If all you have is that definition (or expansion by minors or something), you can prove invertibility by defining the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) (essentially explicitly calculating the inverse), but this is a lot more work. The implication $\text{invertibility}\implies\text{independent rows}$ should not be too hard, though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Yes, those were typos... my bad. The reason I fretted writing a proof about that last observation was more so because I couldn't think of how one can prove that each product has an entry from each row; it seems quite straightforward. As for the contradiction, I see... so the complexity of the proof is dependent on the way we define the determinant. Again, thank you!